# Oracle program “lsnrctl” is missing after the installation of Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I recently downloaded Oracle SQL Developer and when making a new connection inorder to start my own DB I was unable to due to this error below:

[image]

> IO Error the Network Adapter could not establish the connection.

From looking online this error is generated from the 'listener' service lsnrctl but I cannot find it on my system.

Am I supposed to download or install any additional programs if I want to create a database besides Oracle SQL developer since I feel something is missing.

Comment: Did you actually install a database? (SQL Developer is just an "IDE".)

Comment: And if you installed the Oracle database locally, did you start it?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer doesn't include a database.

Your connection is asking to connect to Oracle Express Edition, XE - which you would have to download and install separately.

I talk about this [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/).